# SharePoint list: Reminder based on column value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, reminder

I have SharePoint list and I want to send a reminder to group of people based on column value. For example: [D] Daily reminder, [W] Weekly reminder ...etc

And, I would like to have custom message for each reminder.

How can this be done?

Comment: workflow or Timerjob both can do